# how to get all the number of low-dimension-numpy in the high-dimension numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

After searching around for a decent solutions and found that everything out there was difficult to use.

```
a = [[0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]

b = [[0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

So how to get the numbers (b in a), for the above, return 2.

Comment: Explain how it should be `2`?

Comment: a[:2, 0:3] = [[0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
 
a[2:4, 0:3] = [[0 0 1]
[1 1 1]]

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely.Can you provided more solution for the following cases ?
if a = [[0 0 1 1]
   [1 1 1 1]
   [0 0 1 0]
   [1 0 0 1]
   [0 1 1 1]]

b = [[0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not too clear about different cases that this problem can have, like overlapping, etc., but if you want to check only the intersection from start of `a`'s rows and don't want to take the overlapped sub-arrays into the consideration here is a solution by splitting the `a` based on `b`'s shape:

```
In [22]: x_a, y_a = a.shape

In [23]: x_b, y_b = b.shape

In [24]: sum((b == arr).all() for arr in np.vsplit(a[:,:y_b], x_a//x_b))
Out[24]: 2
```

Explanation:

`np.vsplit(a[:,:y_b], x_a//x_b)` will give you the first `y_b` items from each row in `a`, splited based to equal `x_a//x_b` sized chunks.

```
In [25]: np.vsplit(a[:,:y_b], x_a//x_b)
Out[25]: 
[array([[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]])]
```

And the following generator expression within `sum` will give you number of equal sub arrays to `b`.

```
In [24]: sum((b == arr).all() for arr in np.vsplit(a[:,:y_b], x_a//x_b))
Out[24]: 2
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely.Can you provided more solution for the following cases ?if a = [[0 0 1 1]
   [1 1 1 1]
   [0 0 1 0]
   [1 0 0 1]
   [0 1 1 1]]
b = [[0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]

Comment: @Taufik_TF What's your expected output here? Can you solve it using this answer?

Comment: Out[24]: 2 is OK. Don't care the index in the A